# Como hacer que el usuario ponga exactamente 4 digitos

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer que el usuario ponga exactamente 4 digitos incluyendo ceros
por ejemplo: 0001  0002  0100 etc. Y si por ejemplo ingresa mas de 4 le marque error, tanto si tiene menos de 4 digitos, como si tiene mas de 4 digitos, y que el usuario lo tenga que volver a escribir hasta que cumpla con 4 digitos exactos.
 y necesito que tampoco acepte letras.
hice esto:

```
int agregar() {
    system("cls");
    char id2[4];
    cout<<"Ingrese ID: ";
    do{
       cin.ignore();

       gets(id2);
       if(id2[0]==0 ||id2[1]==0||id2[2]==0||id2[3]==0 || id2[4]!=0){
          system("cls");
          cout<<"Error, el ID debe ser de 4 digitos: ";
       }
} while(id2[0]==0 ||id2[1]==0||id2[2]==0||id2[3]==0&& id2[4]==0);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Quiero hacer que el usuario ponga exactamente 4 dígitos incluyendo ceros por ejemplo: 0001 0002 0100 etc.

Lo más fácil es leer una cadena y comprobar si es de longitud cuatro, después comprobar si todos los caracteres de la cadena son números:

```
int agregar() {
    int resultado{};

    while (true) {
        std::string input;
        std::cout << "Ingrese ID: ";
        std::cin >> input;

        // Si la longitud no es cuatro, repetimos
        if (input.length() != 4)
            continue;

        // Si la entrada es numérica acabamos, si no repetimos.
        if (std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), [](auto c) { return std::isdigit(c); }))
        {
            resultado = std::stoi(input);
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNT8MwDD0vv8LApZXGGF@XdezEhTNHhJCXms4iS6rEEULTfhC/gx820nXrqAY4pzw/2@8l1nV9Xmm92Zyx1SaWBFN2QTzhcqYOWELYVj8RNJXzLIseTWv5qGmmFKRgK4CVpwp9lsNqi@1xTyEawdKt1oXqMu8LNgSZ@Eg/C5oIUk4mrYrUoI5SHKe1iwLTKZw@2DQ2EDzcT@D0NyJbmM32fXr5iwt4ZDAIxtmKJZZgHVAAHVG8GybhNQkvXehV8Stk224jQ7aSRfJ7cgc3eY/UhHZW2Eb6aypZ8VhiM9HG5denZ42AGueYRg4hcCOn0zA6ErG1h8a8uNedoDlVbLN82LodkS2by9NzhlEc6PTOqZ9Eb9un4VBy8p3pvIB1nqtB03l15KP7P7jbf43jdmJeHLHnaZ3e@vC6dyMT6J@3OhSpg4Ct5k5HS0qEZruW2FhWKzXYbdRJt4dJ3WBXOy7UerO5vLq@uVU1SjoK57pU4/H4Un0D)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int controlledInput () {
    char tecla = ' ';
    string auxString = "";

    while (1) { 
     if (getch()) {
        tecla = getch();

        if (tecla == 13) { // Si es un enter, sale, 13 es para enter
            break;
        }

        if (tecla == 8 && auxString.length() > 0) { // El ascii code 8 es para backspace
            auxString.erase( auxString.end()-1 );
         }

        if (auxString.length() >= 4) { // No mas de 4 caracteres
            cout << "Demasiados caracteres!" << endl;
            Sleep(1000);

        } else if (isdigit(tecla)) {
            auxString += tecla;

         }
         system("cls");
         cout << auxString << endl; 
      }
    }

    return stoi (auxString, 10); // C++ 11 Required, convertier string to int
}

int main () {
    int number = controlledInput ();

    cout << "Ingresaste el numero " << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como [tag:c++], tu respuesta usa dos cabeceras de [tag:c] y una cabecera dependiente de sistema operativo.